# Django upload image using page slud/id

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to add the ability to upload an image to a post but having issues.

The image field is in its own model but uses a foreign key to show which post it relates to.
At the moment the upload button does not post the form but also how would I use the post page url/slug/id as the image foreign key.

Would i need to call it in the html post page?

**views.py**

```
def designUpload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

```
**models.py**
class Designs(models.Model):
    forbrief = models.ForeignKey(Brief, on_delete=CASCADE)
    postedby = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    design = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Designs
        fields = ["design",]
```

**HTML Form**

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="image" name="mydesign">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: your question is not clear!

Comment: @HamzaLachi basically. I want to be able to upload a design using the designs model which will use the page/url id the form is on to use that as the foreign key?